# Passing inherited object to a WCF service using JSON

Tags: c#, python, json, wcf, soap

I have two classes that I have listed below

```cs
public Class Vehicle
{
   int wheels { get ; set}
}

public Class Car:Vehicle
{
   int topspeed { get; set ;}
}

//This is the container class

public Class Message
{
   string ConatinerName { get; set;}
   Vehicle Container;
}
```

I have defined a service contract which looks like the one below. This webservice has two end points enabled. One is SOAP and the other is Json

```
//this function gets a message object, looks into the container
public Message GetMessage(Message Input)
{
   Car mycar = (Car)Message.Container;
   mycar.topspeed = 200;
   Message retMessage = new Message();
   retMessage.ContainerName ="Adjusted Car Speed";
   retMessage.Container = mycar;
   return retMessage;
}
```

When I run the WCF webservice, visual studios native test client is able to call the service with a Message object and provided the option to pass in either a car or a vehcile objet in the Message container. The VS client uses the soap endpoint as per the raw data that gets passed in.
To test the json endpoint of the service

I am using a simple client written in Python that calls the above webservice `GetMessage()` method using json data format. I pass in a `Car` object but when the service actually get

The webservice method gets the data, the container inside the object only contains the Vehicle object.
I have examined the Request Context that the webmethod receives and it shows the correct json string is received(as it was sent) but .net somehow strips away the `Car` class property and only passes in the `Vehicle` property. So the cast to car inside `GetMessage()` throws an exception saying you are trying to cast a vehicle to a car which is an invalid cast.

Now I understand the `Container` inside the `Message` is of type `Vehicle`, but for the SOAP end point, I am able to pass in a car object and a vehicle object but for the json end point only a Vehicle object can be passed in through the `Message` container.

My question is how can I make the .NET runtime recognize that I am trying to pass in a `Car` and not a `Vehicle`?

My json client code is posted below

```
import urllib2, urllib, json

def get_json(url):
                f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
                resp = f.read()
                f.close()
                return json.loads(resp)

def post(url, data):
                headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
                request = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
                f = urllib2.urlopen(request)
                response = f.read()
                f.close()
                return response

geturl = 'http://localhost:24573/Service1.svc/json/GetMessage'
sendurl = 'http://localhost:24573/Service1.svc/json/SendMessage'

msg = get_json(geturl)
print 'Got', msg
print 'Sending...'
retval = post(sendurl, json.dumps(msg))
print 'POST RESPONSE', retval
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a similar problem using Python to call a WCF with JSON.  Remarkably, what fixed it for me was ensuring that the `__type` key came first in the post request.

For example, `json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True)` would return something like this.  The WCF service didn't like that because `__type` was not first in the `Container`.  So, my suggestion would be to ensure that __type is first.  (Also, I'm quite surprised that `sort_keys` is not recursive.)

Wrong:

```
{"Container": {"Model": "El Camino", "TopSpeed": 150, "Wheels": 0, "__type": "Car:#WcfService1"},"WrapperName": "Car Wrapper"}
```

Right:

```
{"Container": {"__type": "Car:#WcfService1", "Model": "El Camino", "TopSpeed": 150, "Wheels": 0},"WrapperName": "Car Wrapper"}
```

Simple python test client.

```
import urllib2, urllib, json

def get_json(url):
    f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    resp = f.read()
    f.close()
    return json.loads(resp)


def post(url, data):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    request = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
    f = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    response = f.read()
    f.close()
    return response

geturl = 'http://localhost:24573/Service1.svc/json/GetMessage'
sendurl = 'http://localhost:24573/Service1.svc/json/SendMessage'

msg = get_json(geturl)
print 'Got', msg
print 'Sending...'
retval = post(sendurl, json.dumps(msg))
print 'POST RESPONSE', retval
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute to Vehicle class

[KnownType(typeof("Car"))]

Comment: you mean [KnownType(typeof(Car))]
it helped me when I faced the same problem consuming the WCF service from the native client